# Express.js CookieParser does not get Angular.js $cookies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, cookies, express

I'm trying to get to use the cookies set by Angular.js in my Node.js backend, but it returns undefined...
Can anyone help me?

```js
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookieParser());

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.cookies); // returns undefined
  });

app.listen(3000);
```

Dependencies:
Node.js

- express.js
- cookieparser

Angular.js

- $cookies
- $route

Comment: Do you see cookie set on client side?

Comment: Yes, when I open my resources tab in Google Chrome, it lists the cookie.